# T1 fontenc silently eating letters

Tags: accents, font-encodings

LaTeX is silently dropping accented characters when I use the T1 font encoding.  Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Remove this and it works fine
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\font\tensfb = cmssbx11

\begin{document}

% Note the missing letters in the output
{\tensfb Fr\'echet--Dujmovi\'c}

\end{document}
```

Both latex and pdflatex produce the following output:

[image: LaTeX output]

Does anyone know how to fix this?  I'm guessing it has to do with the (probably old-school) way the font is being selected.  What's the right way to do it?

Comment: font `cmssbx11` almost certainly doesn't contain pre-accented letters, so the T1 encoding isn't doing you any favors here.

Comment: you just seem to want sans serif bold so `\textbf{\textsf{hello}}`

Comment: Yes, easy question. This came up within a .cls file that has been evolving for 7 years (and was originally based on some example that's probably much older).

Comment: Unless the class is older than 1993 it's always been wrong:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

T1-encoding redefines the `\'` so that it points to a position that doesn't exist in your font. Use the normal latex commands to select fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\large 

Fr\'echet--Dujmovi\'c

{\sffamily\bfseries \large Fr\'echet--Dujmovi\'c}

{\fontencoding{OT1}\sffamily\bfseries \large Fr\'echet--Dujmovi\'c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I selected this as the answer because the third line produces output identical to the original text (not sure I understand why the font encoding should affect the weight, though).

Comment: @PatMorin that's because your document specified T1 (8 bit) font encoding, but you selected a 7bit  font, In the last line Ulrike has switched back to the classic OT1 encoding so you get the 7bit font set up for sans serif, matching the font you used.  Note that you get no hyphenation in words with accents in OT1 so unless this is a one-off name, T1 is definitely preferred for non-English documents.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : In this case it's only in section headings, so hyphenation is not really an issue. This is a class file for a journal, so it's more important to keep it looking the same as other articles in the journal.  We may rethink this when we start a new volume next year.

Answer (score 6):

That is to be expected, by using the `\font` primitive directly you have undercut the entire mechanism latex uses to ensure that you get the correct fonts for the correct encodings, so latex thinks you have an 8bit T1 encoded font, but you have loaded a 7bit one.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Remove this and it works fine
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



\begin{document}

% Note the missing letters in the output

{\large\sffamily\bfseries Fr\'echet--Dujmovi\'c}

\end{document}
```

Note that in the log on your original you will see

```
Missing character: There is no � in font cmssbx11!
Missing character: There is no � in font cmssbx11!
```

TeX does not drop the characters with no warning.